# Why does a C null terminator `\0` show up as `\000` during GDB debugging?

Tags: c, gdb, character

During my GDB debugging sessions, I've noticed that null terminator characters, denoting the end of a string, and shown as `\0` in C files, show up as `\000` in GDB when displaying the value of a variable storing such a character.

```
(gdb) print buffer[10]
$2 = 0 '\000'
```

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: Because non-printable characters in strings are by some conventions, written as octal escape codes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GDB seems to *always* use 3 octal digits to display character escapes - and for a good reason_ Consider the following *string*

```
const char *str = "\1\2\3\4\5";
```

then

```
(gdb) p str
$1 = 0x555555556004 "\001\002\003\004\005"
```

This is because C standard says that an escape sequence consists of *maximum* of 3 octal digits. Thus if you write:

```
"\0a"
```

it means string literal of two characters - *null* followed by `a`. But if you write

```
"\01"
```

it means a string literal of one character: ASCII code 1 - *Start-of-Header* control character. In fact the *shortest* way to write ASCII null followed by the *digit `1`* (i.e. ASCII code 49) in a string literal is `"\0001"` The other possibilities are `"\0" "1"` using string concatenation; separate escapes `"\0\61"`; or using hex escapes `\x...`, all of which will be even longer....

So by *always* using 3 octal digits, GDB can produce *consistent* output for strings - such that when copied to a C program will result in the *same* string during runtime. Furthermore the output routine is simpler because it does not need to consider the following character.

Answer (score 2):

This record `'\0'` is an octal escape sequence of a character constant (literal).

An octal escape sequence may contain at most three octal digits.